# How to start a process automatically, according to a certain periodicity, in gxflow?

Tags: genexus

We have a process in GXFlow. Currently, a person starts the process, but we need that the process starts automatically, every month.
Genexus 18 U7
.NET
Web
[genexus](/questions/tagged/genexus)

A task with reminders has been set up but it always works after starting the process manually.
The requirement is that the process starts automatically, by the system, sending a form to an user, depending on the frequency that is configured.

Comment: Carlos, can you set up an operating system task to run whenever you want (once a month, once a day, at a specific time, etc.)? You can call the GXFlow process that checks the timers. https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?43454,Timer+Control